# The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I want to create a foreign key between two database. Happens that the tables have data, so when I'm making the foreign relational there's giving me error.

I found the error happen when your tables have data. So how to not verify existing data?

```
ALTER TABLE [contrato_sigob].[relacion_institucion_categoria]
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_CATEGORIA
CHECK([dbo].[func_CHECK_CATEGORIA](id_categoria)=1);
```

The error says:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHECK_CATEGORIA". The conflict occurred in database "SIGOB_Contraloria", table "contrato_sigob.relacion_institucion_categoria", column 'id_categoria'.
```

Comment: Fix your data first

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? The question is tagged as "mysql" but that looks like MS SQL Server to me.

Comment: @IkeWalker Is Sql Server. The tag suggested me mssql but ignore the tag

Comment: Why you mean about fix the data first? @realspirituals

Comment: If you want a foreign key, why are you implementing a `CHECK` constraint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So how to not verify existing data?

You can create a constraint that will not check your existing records by adding WITH NOCHECK:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT ...
```